# Facebook: different "like" result for page members

Tags: php, facebook

in my script, I fetch `graph.facebook.com/<page_id>/members/<user_id>` with `file_get_contents()` to inspect that the user already liked the page or not. That method worked out just fine for a year now, but now it returns blank JSON array for FEW of the users. Tried to dislike/like again the page, but the result is the same for these users..

Proper return for a user who liked the page:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "John Doe",
         "id": "000000000"
      }
   ]
}
```

Bogus return:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: It could be the user's privacy settings don't allow everyone to see their likes. This could give you this empty data set since Facebook would successfully get the result, then filter it out before returning it to you via the API.

Comment: That's acceptable, but these users never changed the privacy settings, as far as I know. Currently I have 310 "proper" users and 5-6 with the bogus return.

Comment: If these users haven given you their user_likes permission, I can’t see a reason for this happening. Please check if you have this permission (or even request it from them again) – and if this still does not work, file a bug report with Facebook.